# React Rendering Pages Twice

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm working on a React app at the moment, and I've got the assignment to try-catch runtime errors when they occur. I've implemented the ErrorBoundary solution found on the [React website](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html).

Now, this solution works great, but I have a problem. Whenever a page loads, whether this is from navigation or a hard reload, React renders the ErrorBoundary component correctly (because there is an error in a child component), but after a few seconds, renders the child component anyway and then crashes. I have looked all over my code to find the culprit, scoured Google for tangeable errors, but could not find what is causing this behaviour.
This behaviour was already present before the ErrorBoundary solution was implemented. It has been in here since I started working on it a few weeks back.

Also, this behaviour makes it so that when React first renders a page, the `this.props` is empty. Only after the few seconds have passed, will the `this.props` be filled. It hasn't been a problem up until now, while we always check the this.props object for our needed data. But I do not want to hack around this behaviour any longer and find a solution.

I've looked at the component lifecycle functions, but I only really use the constructor and the componentDidMount functions to load and set data, and use the setState function to change data along the way in a few components.

I have as drastic as it sounds removed all code from the render of my components, starting from the top, all the way to the logical last child component, to find out which component is the culprit, but it did not make any difference in the behaviour I'm getting.

Below are some screenshots of what happens:
[image]
[image]

I've started with React, creating the tic-tac-toe example application. But in this tutorial, I did not see behaviour like this.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: You can render the page inside your desired specific condition. Currently the render function is open to all cases in your code. and by the way initialize this.pros={}

Comment: in line 25, is there a typo of this.props or is it a class variable?

Comment: The error of the {this.pros} is intentional, as I want my ErrorBoundary component to catch these kinds of errors and return the error-block you see in the first screenshot.